# How to build a 2D dynamic array parameterised by a 1D dynamic array in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

Is there a way to create a dynamic array by concatenating multiple dynamic arrays in a for -like loop in Office 365 Excel?

Here is a MWE (my actual columns are more complex than just using `randarray`.

What I am trying to achieve is in cells B2:F4 in this figure:[image: screenshot of desired outcome]

The formulas as a screenshot...
[image]

... and as text:

```
index: =SEQUENCE(,5)
desired: =RANDARRAY(3,5, B1#,B1#+1,TRUE)
workaround: =RANDARRAY(3,,B1,B1+1,TRUE)
attempt 1 (hstack): =HSTACK(RANDARRAY(3,,B1#,B1#+1,TRUE))
attempt 2 (bycol): =BYCOL(B$1#,LAMBDA(m,RANDARRAY(3,1,m,m+1,TRUE)))
```

I do notice (see screenshot) that there is a "Nested Array" error, That seems significant. I'd appreciate any feedback, examples, or clarifications, even if the answer is "not possible in 2023".

Comment: So what are your “_actual columns_” and the actual desired output? A solution to the specific problem shown could be `=MAKEARRAY(3, 5, LAMBDA(r,c, RANDBETWEEN(c, c+1)))` but that may or may not help with your actual data.

Comment: Further to my comment above, you can use `INDEX()` with `MAKEARRAY()` to iterate through the rows or columns of the 1D array. For example: `=MAKEARRAY(3, COLUMNS(B1#), LAMBDA(r,c, RANDBETWEEN(INDEX(B1#,c), INDEX(B1#,c)+1)))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I think my MWE is a bit confusing. I **don't** want the empty rows. The empty rows are the bug. What I'd like is for `desired` to work like `workaround` but with a single array instead of using the drag-paste functionality.

Comment: @DjC thanks, `makearray` is the function I was missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `RANDARRAY` Applied On Repeating Rows

**Repeat Rows**

- This 'repeats' the row `3` times resulting in `d` (imagine `B1:F1` copied to `B2:F4`).
- Then it uses `d` and `d+1` with the `RANDARRAY` function.

```
=LET(data,B1#,rows,3,increment,1,
    d,IF(SEQUENCE(rows),data),
RANDARRAY(COLUMNS(d),rows,d,d+increment,1))
```

[image]

**MAKEARRAY (similar to DjC's suggestions in your comments)**

```
=LET(data,B1#,rows,3,increment,1,
MAKEARRAY(rows,COLUMNS(data),LAMBDA(r,c,
    LET(num,INDEX(data,c),
    RANDBETWEEN(num,num+increment)))))
```

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The more I look at it, the more I think I'll have to delete it. It's kind of the same as OP's much simpler *"workaround"*.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the workaround is simpler, but this is a workflow in a much longer calculation, so I'm happy to eat some complexity here to make all my dependent formulas dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 this answers the question as posed and I think it is useful to the community. This answer doesn't quite work for me because my question omits an important point: the function I really need to use creates a column output. I'll enter a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, here's a solution that defines a recursive `LAMBDA()` function ***directly within*** the `LET()` function by using a *fixed-point combinator* (p.s. I stumbled across this method on reddit):

```
=LET(
F, LAMBDA(X,a,b,c,[val],[num],
   LET(
   d, RANDARRAY(, COLUMNS(a), a, a+b, TRUE),
   v, IF(ISOMITTED(val), d, VSTACK(val, d)),
   n, IF(ISOMITTED(num), 1, num),
   IF(n<c, X(X, a, b, c, v, n+1), v))),
F(F, B1#, 1, 3))
```

Just to be clear, **NO** custom function is defined in Name Manager with this method. The above formula can be entered directly in any cell.

**Results:**

[image: recursive_let.png]

**Explanation:**

Normally, in order to create a recursive lambda function, it needs to be defined in Name Manager. For example, you might define the name `RANDMULT` with the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(array,increment,rows,[initial_value],[start],
   LET(
   d, RANDARRAY(, COLUMNS(array), array, array+increment, TRUE),
   v, IF(ISOMITTED(initial_value), d, VSTACK(initial_value, d)),
   n, IF(ISOMITTED(start), 1, start),
   IF(n<rows, RANDMULT(array, increment, rows, v, n+1), v)))
```

As you can see, the `RANDMULT()` function calls itself again if the condition to exit the function has not been met. The optional *[initial_value]* and *[start]* parameters are where we pass the results of each iteration of `RANDMULT()` until the number of iterations are equal to the number specified in the *rows* parameter. This is basically the same idea as a "For Next" loop in VBA. The formula `=RANDMULT(B1#, 1, 3)` could then be used in any cell.

Unfortunately, if we attempt to define the same recursive lambda function as a name ***directly within*** `LET()` (rather than in Name Manager), it will return the `#NAME?` error. Due to the constraints of the `LET()` function, a name cannot refer to itself by name in its own definition... it must be fully defined before it can be used. This is where the *fixed-point combinator* logic comes in.

Referring back to the first formula above, when the `F()` function is defined, instead of calling itself again within its own definition, it calls the `X()` function, which is passed to `F()` as the first parameter. Once the `F()` function is fully defined, it's used by passing the function to itself to create the recursion.

Anyways, I realize this is not the most efficient solution for this specific question. I just thought it was interesting. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Great stuff. Keep'em coming.